# Dynamically change title of a chart in amcharts 4

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

How can I change the title of a loaded chart using javascript? The following doesn't work with external data

https://codepen.io/abdfahim/pen/zYOPvPx

```
var chart = am4core.createFromConfig({
    "titles": [
        {
            "text": "ABCD",
            "fontSize": 25,
            "marginBottom": 10
        }
    ],
    "dataSource": {
        "url": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/sample_data_serial.json"
    },
    "xAxes": [
        {
            "type": "CategoryAxis",
            "dataFields": {
                "category": "year"
            }
        }
    ],
    "yAxes": [
        {
            "type": "ValueAxis"
        }
    ],
    "series": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSeries",
            "name": "Cars",
            "dataFields": {
                "categoryX": "year",
                "valueY": "cars"
            }
        }
    ]
}, "chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

function changeTitle()
{
  chart.titles[0].text = "New Title";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AmCharts v4 uses [lists](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/listtemplate/) for the majority of its array-like objects, so using subscripts will not work. It's recommended to use the accessor methods provided by the list to get at the object you want to change, such as `getIndex`:

```
chart.titles.getIndex(0).title = "New title"
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/271c90910a87ec56808efae1c177e95c?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case some one will hit my same issue, I found this solution working for me

```
chart.titles.getIndex(0).text = "new title";
```

this is particularly handy if you are going to refresh the chart each x seconds